# Issue with building Springboot in Maven2

Tags: spring-boot, maven-2, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a Springboot app that uses Spring data jpa in Maven 2 and I get the following error. I have the dependency it is complaining about in the local repository. Any ideas?

```
   Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar': 
POM 'org.jboss.shrinkwrap:shrinkwrap-bom' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this; I had to add the BOM dependencies one-by-one to the project POM explicitly. Looks like Maven 2 doesn't like something about transitive BOM dependencies.